# Confusion Matrix Sensitivity & Specificity length match but data cannot have more levels than reference

Tags: r, predict

Problem:

Confusion Matrix needed for measuring Sensitivity & Specificity.

Issue:

For confusion matrix data, I have levels that match, in Confusion matrix, data cannot have more levels than the reference, so when my levels match (e.g. below in list), what then is the error referring to with respect to 'data cannot have more levels than the reference'? the reference is the 'model_prediction' [last length() / str(). My dependent variable is a factor variable.

Effort Tried:

For the R code, first I ran prediction with factor results and included na.action:

```
loans_predict_fcm <- factor(predict(full, newdata = data_train, type = "response", na.action = na.pass))
```

With results from a separate table(), e.g, pred_table; I was successful in calculating Sensitivity and Specificity ok using formula. However, I would like to cross confirm this with a confusionMatrix(). But I'm having trouble getting confusionMatrix() to work.

```
Sensitivity <- 100*(pred_table[1,1])/sum(pred_table[1,1] + pred_table[1,1])
Specificity <- 100*(pred_table[2,2])/sum(pred_table[2,1] + pred_table[2,2])
```

When I attempt to run the confusionMatrix() with the factored predict(). Then inspect the levels, and find them not matching, so that is why confusionMatrix() failed on data cannot have more levels than reference, which in this run model_prediction.

```
confusionMatrix(loans_predict_fcm, model_prediction, positive="1")
identical (levels(loans_predict_fcm), levels(model_prediction))
> FALSE
```

```
> length(loans_predict_fcm)
[1] 27724
> str(loans_predict_fcm)
 Factor w/ 27424 levels "0.13079979710253",..: 15967 9625 15966 10703 7830 12394 21291 15023 17920 18442 ...
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:27724] "11413" "2561" "25337" "1643" ...
> length(loans_train_data$statusRank)
[1] 27724
> str(loans_train_data$statusRank)
 Factor w/ 2 levels "Bad","Good": 2 2 2 1 1 2 2 2 1 2 ...
> length(model_prediction)
[1] 27724
> str(model_prediction)
 Factor w/ 2 levels "Bad","Good": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the Confusion Matrix Sensitivity & Specificity issue, the column names and row names had difference, so I was able to solve it using a custom function, that was basically setdiff on colnames() and rownames(), and creating a matrix vector mat.or.vec() for the length of missings colnames.